# chat application database design

Tags: android, database-design, signalr, chat

I'm attempting to create a chat application in android, much like whatsapp. The chat view will have list of chat sessions and clicking the chat session will open up the chat window where the users will chat with each other. The chat session will show the name of the user at the other end and their last message sent.
Here's my attempt at designing the database

[image]

Is this a correct schema for the database that will accomplish what I'm trying to achieve? I'm going to be using SignalR for real time communication. I want to know if I'm headed in the right direction.

Comment: This really isn't a code/design review website. This looks a bit too basic to me, there's no delivery confirmation, no device indication, etc. IDs should probably be device-generated (UUIDs), so that you can dispose of messages in-flight properly. Also, really look closely into SignalR, as the Android and iOS clients aren't... uhm... great.

Comment: To design chat application database better go for any nosql db.It would be most suitable and more easier too